# How can one close a channel in a defer block safely?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

Consider the following [example](https://go.dev/play/p/s6nWV7P84lQ):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    done := make(chan bool)
    defer func() {
        fmt.Println("exiting..")
        done <- true
        close(done)
    }()
    go func(ticker *time.Ticker, done chan bool) {
        for {
            select {
            case <-done:
                fmt.Println("DONE!")
                break
            case <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("TICK!...")
            }
        }
    }(ticker, done)
    time.Sleep(7 * time.Second)
}
```

The goroutine waiting to receive from `done` never receives as (I am guessing) the main goroutine finished beforehand. However if I change the sleep time of the main goroutine to 8 seconds **it receives a message**; Why is there this dependency on the sleep time?

Is it because there is that second difference that keeps the goroutine alive and the there isn't enough time to kill it?

How would I than kill the goroutine gracefully?

Comment: What is the point of trying to close `done` at the end of `main`? The process is exiting, there's nothing left to do.

Comment: It is pure luck. Channel will be closed when main returns. At that point, it is a race between the goroutine to detect it and the program to terminate.

Comment: My issue (in a real world example, not this one) is that main can exit in many different points and I dont wish to close the channel on each of those points but have it in a defer block to ensure the channel safely closes.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yeah I was considering that, is there any way to ensure the goroutine remains alive for the channel to close gracefully though?

Comment: You are sending a value over the channel to signal `done`, there is no reason to call `close` here at all. Normally you would use `close` itself as that signal, but the fact that you're not waiting for the goroutine is probably your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that main does not return before the goroutine finishes.
The simplest way to do this is using a WaitGroup:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
defer wg.Wait()
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    // …
```

Note that `defer`s run  in reverse order, so you must put `defer wg.Wait()` before `defer close(done)`, otherwise it will deadlock.